# Radiobuttons in a radioGroup in a multiple rows

Tags: android, android-view, android-inflate, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

Is it possible to create a RadioGroup that will hold radio buttons by 3 in a row? I've checked the internet for an implementation and I found one, but it was not working. The thing is that I need to add them programatically, and they should be grouped 3 per row.

Can someone tell me how can I populate a radioGroup with RadioButtons so they are aligned 3 per row.

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem.see:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32846410/how-to-align-radiobuttons-in-a-radiogroup

may be it h

Answer (score 0):

Radiogroup inherits from LinearLayout.
So, set the RadioGroup `orientation` attribute to `"horizontal"`

Comment: yes but if horizontal all of them will be in one row, how to put them 3 per row. That is the question

Comment: Make several rows. I think of these RadioGroups as the items in a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Radio Group inherits from the LinearLayout ViewGroup so you can make this possible by setting orientation on the viewgroup `android:orientation="horizontal"`

```
  <RadioGroup
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton
        android:text="Radio 1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton
        android:text="Radio 2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton
        android:text="Radio 3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: "3 per row" implies multiple rows. How does this address it?