# How to align radiobuttons in a radiogroup

Tags: android

I have a radiogroup in which I have 4 radiobuttons in it.I want them to be align as a two horizontal lines i.e two radiobuttons horizontally and other two radiobuttons horizontally and below the first horizontal radiobuttons.

How can i accomplish this without changing its functionality

It means only one radiobutton can be selected.

Here's my simple code:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup_relation_options"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/HeadingText"
    android:background="#4269c6" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton_friend"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_radiobutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Friend"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton_business"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_radiobutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="We&apos;ve done Business Together"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton_colleague"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_radiobutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Colleague"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton_other"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_radiobutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Other"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: use `android:weight`

Comment: Please attach your XML code. I will edit it and give you solution

Comment: hey, see my edited code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another simple solution.

**main_activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/one_radio_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="one" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/two_radio_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="two" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/three_radio_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="three" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/four_radio_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="four" />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

  private RadioButton mOneRadioButton;
  private RadioButton mTwoRadioButton;
  private RadioButton mThreeRadioButton;
  private RadioButton mFourRadioButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mOneRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.one_radio_btn);
    mTwoRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.two_radio_btn);
    mThreeRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.three_radio_btn);
    mFourRadioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.four_radio_btn);

    mOneRadioButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mTwoRadioButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mThreeRadioButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mFourRadioButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.one_radio_btn:
            mOneRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            mTwoRadioButton.setChecked(false);
            mThreeRadioButton.setChecked(false);
            mFourRadioButton.setChecked(false);

            break;
        case R.id.two_radio_btn:

            mOneRadioButton.setChecked(false);
            mTwoRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            mThreeRadioButton.setChecked(false);
            mFourRadioButton.setChecked(false);
            break;
        case R.id.three_radio_btn:

            mOneRadioButton.setChecked(false);
            mTwoRadioButton.setChecked(false);
            mThreeRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            mFourRadioButton.setChecked(false);
            break;
        case R.id.four_radio_btn:

            mOneRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            mTwoRadioButton.setChecked(false);
            mThreeRadioButton.setChecked(false);
            mFourRadioButton.setChecked(true);
            break;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution but its pretty much lengthy.Thank you for the solution

Answer (score 0):

RadioGroup is subclass of LinearLayout,if you want it to support multiline,then need to overwrite it,but now has such a widget can use:[MultiLineRadioGroup](https://github.com/a284628487/MultiLineRadioGroup),help the sample could help you.

Comment: i didn't know about that.Thanks for sharing such a valueable information.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using 2 radioGroups

1. create `RadioGroup` with `android:orientation = "horizontal"`
2. put 2 radio buttons in it.
3. create another `RadioGroup` same as above.
4. make sure Id of `RadioGroups` and `RadioButtons` are distinct.
5. use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` to set same `OnCheckedChangeListener` on both the groups.

   `//assuming activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener
   rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
   rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);`
6. call `clearCheck` on other radio group (group 1 if check has been performed in group 2)
7. check both groups for a checked `RadioButton` while performing an operation .

Comment: @Abhay I've added snippet for step 5

Answer (score 0):

Try it with two different LinearLayout :

```
<RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: I tried it already.Putting linear layout between radiogroups overrides the functionality of radiogroup.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this and tell me if it fits the requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup_relation_options"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/HeadingText"
    android:background="#4269c6" >

    <!-- 2 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

      <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton_friend"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_radiobutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Friend"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton_business"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_radiobutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="We&apos;ve done Business Together"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
    </TableRow>

<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >
<RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton_colleague"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_radiobutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Colleague"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radiobutton_other"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:button="@drawable/custom_radiobutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Other"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
    </TableRow>
</RadioGroup>

</TableLayout>
```

I have used table layout here, so that there are 2 rows of RadioButtons.

Comment: This i also tried before.Setting radiobutton is no big problem.The problem is the functionality.This way overrides the functionality of the radiogroup.i.e only one radiobutton should be selected at a time.btw! thanks for the effort and your time

Comment: i made small adjustment, just copy paste it and please tell me, even if you have tried it, please try it once more